# Indicate ComboBox Value Is Dirty

Tags: wpf, combobox

I'm looking for a good way to indicate the value of a ComboBox is dirty. With TextBoxes I set the Background to yellow but that looks a little funny with the ComboBox because of the 3d-ness. Any ideas about how to show the ComboBox value is dirty while keeping the look clean and pretty?

Comment: Add a border color? "Looking clean and pretty" is pretty subjective.

Comment: Yeah I realize its a subjective question. I was just looking for ideas. Also wasn't sure if there was a "standard" out there for showing that type of info.

Comment: I would try asking on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping the ComboBox in a border and setting the thickness and color when the value is dirty. This way the 3D appearance of the ComboBox is preserved.

```
<Border Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <Border.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RankIsDirty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Resources>
    <ComboBox Name="DimensionsComboBox"    
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=Dimensions}}" 
        SelectedIndex="{Binding Rank}"  
    </ComboBox>
</Border>
```

There were also good suggestions left on my question at: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11007/how-to-indicate-combobox-value-is-dirty

Answer (score 0):

A universal way to flag something as dirty is with an asterisk, however this might be misinterpreted as "required" depending on the context of your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

Red border, error image adorner combined with error explanation tooltip are standards used in WPF. But having said that you can achieve many extravagant effects.

Comment: Thats for errors not for IsDirty. In this case, the value being dirty doesn't mean there is an error, it just means they user hasn't saved yet.